# How to override LWC lightning record form Cancel button

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

I'm using a lightning record form to create a new cord in a Customer Community. Just wondering is there any way to override the standard 'Cancel' button behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation), **This event has no default behavior that can be canceled. You can't call preventDefault() on this event.**

[image]

You can customise only onload and onsubmit events. If you need more customized usage, you need to implement `lightning-edit-form`

Answer (score 1):

I have used like as steated below and it is worked for me

```
 <lightning-record-form  object-api-name='Contact' fields={layoutfields}
                    columns="2" mode="edit" onsubmit={handleSubmit} oncancel={closeModal}  onsuccess={handleSuccess} class="full forcePageBlock forceRecordLayout">
                </lightning-record-form>
```

[Lightning:recordForm cancel button unresponsive](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228556/lightningrecordform-cancel-button-unresponsive?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in documentation, use the oncancel attribute to do anything we want in the js file.

In my case, I used the function which closes the modal pop up window.

.HTML file

```
<div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <lightning-record-form object-api-name="Tissue_Log__c" record-id={recordId} columns="2" mode="edit"
        layout-type="Full" onsuccess={handleSuccess} oncancel={customHideModalPopup}>
     </lightning-record-form>
</div>
```

.js file

```
    @track customFormModal = false; 
    customShowModalPopup() {        
        this.customFormModal = true;
    }
    customHideModalPopup() {    
        this.customFormModal = false;
    }
```